# REST API Authentication with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to implement an authentication on my current Java Restful API (Jersey) by following [this tutorial](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1814/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-ee-7-jax-rs-2-0-simple-rest-api-authentication-authorization-with-custom-http-header/). I put all new authentication classes inside a "auth" package. When I run the jquery example code, it says that "DemoBusinessRESTResourceProxy is an interface and cannot be instantiated". So I research and decided to put the Jersey annotations on DemoBusinessRESTResource and delete DemoBusinessRESTResourceProxy:

```
@Local
@Path("access/")
@Stateless(name = "DemoBusinessRESTResource", mappedName = "ejb/DemoBusinessRESTResource")
public class DemoBusinessRESTResource {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6663599014192066936L;

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            @FormParam("username") String username,
            @FormParam("password") String password) {

        Authenticator authenticator = Authenticator.getInstance();
        String serviceKey = httpHeaders
                .getHeaderString(HTTPHeaderNames.SERVICE_KEY);

        try {
            String authToken = authenticator.login(serviceKey, username,
                    password);

            JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            jsonObjBuilder.add("auth_token", authToken);
            JsonObject jsonObj = jsonObjBuilder.build();

            return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.OK).entity(
                    jsonObj.toString()).build();

        } catch (final LoginException ex) {
            JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            jsonObjBuilder.add("message",
                    "Problem matching service key, username and password");
            JsonObject jsonObj = jsonObjBuilder.build();

            return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .entity(jsonObj.toString()).build();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/demo-get-method")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response demoGetMethod() {
        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        jsonObjBuilder.add("message", "Executed demoGetMethod");
        JsonObject jsonObj = jsonObjBuilder.build();

        return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.OK).entity(
                jsonObj.toString()).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/demo-post-method")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response demoPostMethod() {
        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        jsonObjBuilder.add("message", "Executed demoPostMethod");
        JsonObject jsonObj = jsonObjBuilder.build();

        return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(
                jsonObj.toString()).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/logout")
    public Response logout(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        try {
            Authenticator authenticator = Authenticator.getInstance();
            String serviceKey = httpHeaders
                    .getHeaderString(HTTPHeaderNames.SERVICE_KEY);
            String authToken = httpHeaders
                    .getHeaderString(HTTPHeaderNames.AUTH_TOKEN);

            authenticator.logout(serviceKey, authToken);

            return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT)
                    .build();
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(
                    Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    private Response.ResponseBuilder getNoCacheResponseBuilder(
            Response.Status status) {
        CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
        cc.setNoCache(true);
        cc.setMaxAge(-1);
        cc.setMustRevalidate(true);

        return Response.status(status).cacheControl(cc);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm getting this error:

> A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB BusinessRESTResource, method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.rest.auth.DemoBusinessRESTResource.login(javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getHeaderString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

[image: client error]

I'm new in Java WS and I'm totally lost.

Comment: I recommend using [Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) instead.

Comment: Thats it? No help at all? I dont use maven on my project. How to do that?

Comment: I se it as help - If someone wrote it before you, why do it? regarding maven - [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) is what I got when I googled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was the jar version files.